# Question, why is my program not processing when I call the checkInteger function?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements, program-entry-point, statements

Why is my program not processing when I call the checkInteger function?

```py
def main():
    print("Kaylees Prime Number Checker")
    numChoice = int(input("Please type a number: "))
    checkInteger()

def checkInteger(numChoice):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print("Your number is not prime. ")
    else:
        print("Your number is prime.")

main()
```

Comment: Format your code, please. Also, clarify what you mean by "not processing". As far as I can tell, this code should throw an exception; is that what's happening?

Comment: my program will print out "Kaylees Prime Number Checker" and then will ask Please type a number but then tells me missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'. I see you guys are saying I need an argument but I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass an argument to the function checkInteger, since it is defined to take one in your definition.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need an argument for checkInteger, also you should name your parameter number, or change number to numChoice. either way, it has to be the same